# Why can't we declare constants with default value?

Tags: java, constants, declaration, default-value, final

The code below gives me an error `The blank final field a may not have been initialized`.

```
public class Test {

   public static final int a;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
}
```

---

- Why can't the constant hold the default value of an integer?

Comment: Because it could lead to develop errors.

Comment: public static final int a=0; And everything will be fine ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that wouldn't make much sense. How many immutable primitive constants *with default value* would you need in your lifetime? For reference, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html - the only actual values you'd get as constants are literal `0` (cast to different numeric types, but still a `0`, mind me), `false` and `null`. Sun made the design decision to disallow `final` with no value specified ([8.3.1.2 final Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2), note the phrase ***definitely assigned*** there) quite sensibly: in 99.9% of the actual cases when it is encountered by a compiler it is simply due to programmer's error (forgetting to specify a value), rather than a conscious design choice.

That said, you should know that you actually *can* do that.

```
public class Test {

   public static int a0; // inited to default value
   public static final int a = a0; // final with a default value

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It can hold a default value, the problem is (as stated by the error message) is that you must specify which value for `a` that should be the default value for your application, e.g.

```
public static final int a = 42
```

**Edit**

This is dictated by paragraph [8.3.1.2 final Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2) in the Java Language Specification:

> A blank final class variable must be definitely assigned by a static initializer of the class in which it is declared, or a compile-time error occurs

Comment: Down voter, would you mind explain why you think this is a bad answer?

Comment: because you're wrong; `you must specify which value for a that should be the default value for your application` - not only you mustn't specify the *default value of an integer* - actually, you **can't** - it's *already specified by the Java specification* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html `Data Type: int Default Value: 0`- the only way to specify the default value of the integer to different value than `0` would be to edit & recompile own version of Java. You've mistaken *default value of a field* with *initial value of a field*.

Comment: @vaxquis certainly, the default value of `int` is `0`. However, the problem in this question is that a static final variable is left uninitialized, see the JLS reference in my update.

Comment: I believe OP understand that you **have to** initialize it. They want to know why it was designed that way?

Comment: /agree Sotirios : the problem asked by OP is `Why can't the constant hold the default value of an integer?` - the JLS only states that it *can't* be done (which is quite obvious to OP because he noticed the compiler generated an error for it), but doesn't provide any rationale or reasoning for that design choice. Saying "it can't be done because it can't be done" is hardly enlightening nor useful. Also, matsev, you still haven't straightened up the "default" vs "initial" wording mixup.